# Tensorflow Recommenders: what is features in computed_loss method in tfrs.Model class (from Retrieval tutorial)

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, recommendation-engine

I'm following the [Retrieval tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/recommenders/examples/basic_retrieval) from the TFRS (TensorFlow Recommenders) library, and I'm getting confused in this part:

```
class MovielensModel(tfrs.Model):

  def __init__(self, user_model, movie_model):
    super().__init__()
    self.movie_model: tf.keras.Model = movie_model
    self.user_model: tf.keras.Model = user_model
    self.task: tf.keras.layers.Layer = task

  def compute_loss(self, features: Dict[Text, tf.Tensor], training=False) -> tf.Tensor:
    # We pick out the user features and pass them into the user model.
    user_embeddings = self.user_model(features["user_id"])
    # And pick out the movie features and pass them into the movie model,
    # getting embeddings back.
    positive_movie_embeddings = self.movie_model(features["movie_title"])

    # The task computes the loss and the metrics.
    return self.task(user_embeddings, positive_movie_embeddings)
```

Which is followed by this:

```
model = MovielensModel(user_model, movie_model)
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adagrad(learning_rate=0.1))
```

I have a question about these chunks of code:

- when it says `user_embeddings = self.user_model(features["user_id"])` (and also (`self.movie_model(features["movie_title"])`) it seems that `features` is a dictionary, but it's not defined in any part before in the tutorial. I also checked in `compute_loss` source code [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/recommenders/blob/11471d8f6b5d5c50f6f49cd38d3157540c17534b/tensorflow_recommenders/models/base.py#L49), to see if it's an attribute of that method or something, but I don't find anything either... So my question here is, what is `features`? How can the code work well, running that that was not defined before? I tried it outside of the class, by running just this: `user_model(features["user_id"])` and of course it doesn't work saying that `features` is not defined. But why does it work then, when the class is instantiated and later when it's compiled? (second chunk of code above).

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Features is a line of a `tf.data.Dataset` constructed with a dictionnary. You could create the same dataset by using using `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices` on a dictionnary.

For example :

```
dict_ = {'user_id' : [1, 2], 'movie_title' : ['foo', 'bar']}
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dict_)

for features in dataset :
    print(features)
```

Will return :

```
{'user_id': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=1>, 'movie_title': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'foo'>}
{'user_id': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=2>, 'movie_title': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'bar'>}
```

Note that, `dataset['user_id']` will return an error because a `tf.data.Dataset` isn't callable in such a way. The `compute_loss` function of the `MovielensModel(tfrs.Model)` is receiving the items of the `tf.data.Dataset` but it needs tensors to work properly. Thus, the function keep only the tensor associated to the 'user_id' part (or the 'movie_title').

This :

```
for features in dataset:
    print(features['user_id'])
```

Will return a tensor :

```
tf.Tensor(1, shape=(), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor(2, shape=(), dtype=int32)
```

Comment: I was also looking into same tensorflow documentation, I am rather confused about self.movie_model: tf.keras.Model = movie_model what kind of assignment is it . Do you have any insight into this?

Comment: @sakeesh You can use `self.movie_model = movie_model`, it'll work perfectly fine. I believe, they use this type of assignement for educational purposes only.

Comment: Thanks Tony, it looks like its a kind of typing https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Answer (score 0):

In your model.fit() you send in training data. The "features" is that data, that is being fed to the "call" function of your class: "user_model".

You don't have this class in your example here, but if you look into it, you will find the call function there.

Answer (score 0):

If you look carefully at the MovieLens class, you will see that it defines a key-value dictionary called "features".

```
 def compute_loss(self, features: Dict[Text, tf.Tensor], training=False) -> tf.Tensor:
```